# High current/voltage switch

Tags: arduino, capacitor, switches

I working on a coil gun for a demonstration on electromagnetism. I have 2 stages, each with 2 1400uF 450v capacitors that I will be charging up to 375v. I am looking for a switch, or something to the same effect, that can withstand that current and voltage when discharged to the coils. I was also thinking about using an arduino to activate a transistor that can also withstand that current and voltage when the projectile reaches the second stage. Is there a good switch and/or transistor I could use for this? And is the arduino the best thing to use to activate the second stage, or should I use something like a photo-transistor or photo-diode?

Comment: You need to give us some idea of the switching speed you need.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Ref http://www.powerlabs.org/gaussgun.htm
A Reed Relay can safely isolate the control of the trigger.